# Firebase child_removed not working in real-time

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I am following tutsplus Real time web apps with Angularjs and Firebase.
I have main.js (below) which allows me to add and change items in Firebase in real time with no refresh of the browser (in Chrome and Safari).
However when I delete a message from Firebase I have to refresh the browser for the message list to update - so not in real time. I can't see where the problem is.

```
/*global Firebase*/
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name firebaseProjectApp.controller:MainCtrl
 * @description
 * # MainCtrl
 * Controller of the firebaseProjectApp
 */
angular.module('firebaseProjectApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    var rootRef = new Firebase('https://popping-inferno-9738.firebaseio.com/');
    var messagesRef = rootRef.child('messages');

    $scope.currentUser=null;
    $scope.currentText=null;
    $scope.messages=[];

    messagesRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot){
        $timeout(function() {
            var snapshotVal = snapshot.val();
            console.log(snapshotVal);
            $scope.messages.push({
                text: snapshotVal.text,
                user: snapshotVal.user,
                name: snapshot.key()

            });         
        });
    });

    messagesRef.on('child_changed', function(snapshot){
        $timeout(function() {
            var snapshotVal = snapshot.val();
            var message = findMessageByName(snapshot.key());
            message.text = snapshotVal.text;
        });
    });
    messagesRef.on('child_removed', function(snapshot){
        $timeout(function() {
            var snapshotVal = snapshot.val();
            var message = findMessageByName(snapshot.key());
            message.text = snapshotVal.text;
        });
    });
    function deleteMessageByName(name){

        for(var i=0; i < $scope.messages.length; i++){
            var currentMessage = $scope.messages[i];
            if(currentMessage.name === name){
                $scope.messages.splice(i, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    function findMessageByName(name){

        var messageFound = null;
        for(var i=0; i < $scope.messages.length; i++){
            var currentMessage = $scope.messages[i];
            if(currentMessage.name === name){
                messageFound = currentMessage;
                break;
            }
        }
        return messageFound;
    }

    $scope.sendMessage = function(){

        var newMessage = {
            user: $scope.currentUser,
            text: $scope.currentText 
        };

        messagesRef.push(newMessage);
    };


  });
```

Comment: Did you already debug? For example: does the program receive a child_removed event at all?

Comment: Answer below. Note that it took me the better part of half an hour to set up a reproduction of your problem on http://jsbin.com/kewabo/1/. For your next question, either set up such a reproduction yourself or (preferably) reduce the amount of code in your question down to the minimum needed to show the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Many thanks. I somehow didn't see that the deleteMessageByName method wasn't actually called. I will take heed of your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that is invoked when a message is deleted from Firebase:

```
messagesRef.on('child_removed', function(snapshot){
    $timeout(function() {
        var snapshotVal = snapshot.val();
        var message = findMessageByName(snapshot.key());
        message.text = snapshotVal.text;
    });
});
```

This code never actually deletes the message from the HTML/DOM.

There is a convenient `deleteMessageByName` method to handle the deletion. So if you modify the above to this, it'll work:

```
messagesRef.on('child_removed', function(snapshot){
    $timeout(function() {
        deleteMessageByName(snapshot.key());
    });
});
```